# Evaluating the tensors within the mapping function of tf.data.Dataset.map?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible / advisable to evaluate the tensor within the mapping function of tf.data.Dataset.map?  I would like to first create a dataset of filenames, then apply shuffle and repeat to them.  Then, from this dataset, create a new dataset using tf.data.Dataset.map.  The mapping function will load the file and return the contents as a tensor.

The problem is, in order to load the contents of the file, I think I need to eval() the string tensor filename.  But, tensorflow doesn't seem to like it when you use eval() within the mapping function.  Here is a simple test case:

```
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> with sess.as_default():
...     d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3])
...     d2 = d1.map(lambda s: tf.convert_to_tensor(s.eval(session = sess)))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 875, in map  
  return MapDataset(self, map_func)
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1864, in __init__
self._map_func.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 475, in add_to_graph
self._create_definition_if_needed()
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 331, in _create_definition_if_needed
self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 340, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl
self._capture_by_value, self._caller_device)
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 806, in func_graph_from_py_func
outputs = func(*func_graph.inputs)
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1829, in tf_map_func
ret = map_func(nested_args)
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 678, in eval
return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
File "/home/hrbigelow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4981, in _eval_using_default_session
raise ValueError("Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: "
ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.
```

Comment: Could you solve this?